# Implementing generic interfaces

Tags: generics, interface

I have written this code.

```
public interface IMusicInstrument
{
  string InstrumentType(int InstrumentId);                
}

public interface IGuitar<T, K> where T : GuitarBase where K : IMusicInstrument
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string GetType(T t);
}

public class ElectricGuitar : GuitarBaseExtended, IGuitar<ElectricGuitar, IMusicInstrument>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GetType(ElectricGuitar t)
    {
        return "The electric guitar is: " + t.Name;
    }
}
```

I was thinking that because the IMusicInstrument requires that I implement a method called InstrumentType that when I include it as a parameter in my IGuitar interface which is implemented on hte ElectricGuitar class that I would get a compile time error.  However, I do not.

Am I implementing it wrong?

My goal is to implement the IMusicInstrument into the generic typed IGuitar interface so that both the requirements from IMusiInstrument and IGuitar are enforced.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said that `ElectricGuitar` implements `IMusicInstrument`... you've just said that it implements `IGuitar<ElectricGuitar, IMusicInstrument>`, and *that* doesn't have the `InstrumentType` method. It's not clear why you've got the `K` type parameter in `IGuitar<T, K>` at all, given that it's not used within the interface.